# tikz Graph scaled to point

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, axis

I had a graph, that I remember working fine in the past, and suddenly I noticed, that everything is scaled to a tiny point at the bottom of the y-axis. I am not sure if anything at all changed and cannot find the problem.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
            scaled ticks=false,
            axis equal,
            scale=0.5,
            y=1cm,
            x=3cm,
            grid=none,
            xmax=2.5,xmin=-0.01,
            ymin=-1,ymax=5.2,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
            xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2},
            ytick={-1,0,1,2,3,4},
            ylabel = $U(r)$,
            xlabel = $r(r_M)$,
        ]
        \draw[red, thick] (0, 5)--(0, 0)--(2.5, 0);
        \draw[domain=0.84:2.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{0.1*\x^(-12)-0.1*\x^(-6)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Image (one blue and one red curve) is not scaled.

Comment: Maybe `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` after `\usepackage{pgfplots}`  is missing? You can replace `1.15` by another version number or `newest`, but at least `1.11` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pgfplots` version 1.11 `axis cs` is the default coordinate system. But you have to set at least `1.11` as `compat` immedatly after loading package `pgfplots`. If you do not set a value for `compat` then `pre 1.3` is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% comment this to see the issue
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,  %% instead of above two lines this one is enough
            scaled ticks=false,
            axis equal,
            scale=0.5,
            y=1cm,
            x=3cm,
            grid=none,
            xmax=2.5,xmin=-0.01,
            ymin=-1,ymax=5.2,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
            xtick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2},
            ytick={-1,0,1,2,3,4},
            ylabel = $U(r)$,
            xlabel = $r(r_M)$,
        ]
        \draw[red, thick] (0, 5)--(0, 0)--(2.5, 0);
        \draw[domain=0.84:2.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{0.1*\x^(-12)-0.1*\x^(-6)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I would use

```
\plot[domain=0.84:2.5,blue, thick] {0.1*x^(-12)-0.1*x^(-6)};
```

instead the second `\draw` command.